# Does any ide give list of js functions inside php?

Tags: javascript, ide, editor

I use Eclipse to edit php files. It gives me the list of php variables and functions in the otline window.

**Is there any IDE (free of charge) that would provide list of javascripts that are inside my php file?**

I have lots of them and it would be much easier to navigata with such a list.

Comment: Do you mean plain Eclipse editor? Or [pdt](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans for php and Aptana studio should do it and they have also an integrated javascript debugger.

I'm also sure PhpEd does NOT have this function because i use it and it's a feature i want.

Comment: NetBeans does the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Intellij idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) does this. it can recognize languages within languages with a bit of config. Ive only ever used it for javascript within jsp and html, but i see they have a [php app](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)

Dont be put off by *"Most advanced Java IDE"* in the title. Its a great java ide, but it supports many other languages via plugins. Currently im using it to code in python for example.

Comment: IntelliJ is interesting, but isn't it purchase only?

Comment: I don't think my company is going to purchase this one :-( Looks promising though...

Comment: too bad, its a great ide. You can try it for free for 30 days. maybe you should check it out and be able to make a better case, (or hate it)

Comment: @Radek - I can understand, but features cost *something*. JetBrains does deliver.